# FormsAuthentication Login Issue after Deployment

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, deployment, dynamics-crm-2011

I have just finished a project and deployed to the server but am facing few problems while trying to log in in the application.
After following few articles, I managed to set-up the IIS and ended up creating a new log in account named as "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" with permissions for SQLServer.

At the moment, I am able to see the log-in page, but whenever I try to actually log-in, the response comes to the same page so I don't know whether it could be anything related to FormsAuthentication or just SQLServer.

I changed permissions to NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS to see what would happen, and whenever there is no permissions, it returns an error mentioning about the select to verify whether user exists.

I am assuming that the select is being triggered but for some reason the user is not being redirected.

Would anyone have ever experienced that? Any hint?

I would like to state that the application runs ok locally.

----- EDIT [SOLVED]
After spending some time trying to fix this problem I have realized that the problem was actually because I am using CRM and its FilteredViews which allow only users having WindowsAuthentication to retrieve data from those views since they must be part of CRM. Therefore, I needed to change my web.config to continue using Integrated Security as True and changed my IIS config to allow impersonate passing an domain account for log-in.

I hope any1 who may have same problem is able to fix that. Otherwise I am glad to help!

Thanks in advance,
Dem

Answer (score 0):

Check if anonymous access is enabled in IIS/Authentication for your website

Comment: Yes. Only Anonymous Authentication is enable for both server and website.

I tried enabling other ones too but it didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: - Need a bit more info, what does it say in fiddler?
- Whats the issue, you go to log in but instead of signing in it just reloads the page? 
- Is the app pool running under a service account? What about the account you are connecting to SQL? Theres so many things please provide some more information and we can have a better chance at helping you out.

Comment: Hey, After looking further into the project, I have realized that the problem is due to my connection string. On dev I am logging with windows authentication but I need to change the connection for production. 

What is funny about it is that I have created an user for the used databases, and have changed the connection string to login as this particular user and it whatever select I do, comes out without any data.

I am currently using entityFramework to use views from database and read data.

Comment: Below is my current 
connectionString
<add name="MEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/crm.csdl|res://*/crm.ssdl|res://*/crm.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=dev01;initial catalog=ARM;integrated security=False; User Id=portal; Password=portalpw;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

Whenever I change the parameter "Integrated Security" to True, then everything works, as windows authentication is being used.

Comment: So you can use custom Web.configs by right-clicking on Web.config and selecting "Add Config Transforms", and override <connectionStrings> entry in Web.Release.Config, to make life easier :)

Comment: I have found the problem. I am using CRM and that wouldn't allow me to use SQLAuthentication so I had to use impersonate and do WindowsAuthentication. 

Thanks everyone for the replies :)